# How do I stop my minecraft modded server from crashing

Tags: server, minecraft, vps, minecraft-forge

Every time I start the Farming Valley server I get this error:

```
A problem occurred running the Server launcher.java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.run(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:62)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.main(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.<init>(Launch.java:34)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
    ... 6 more
```

I have basically no experience with this and I don't understand what's going on. Any help would greatly be appreciated! Thanks in advance.
It might be good to know that I bought a server from OVH

Comment: I suspect you're using a version of Java that's too new for your version of Minecraft. What version of each are you running?

Comment: Im running version 1.10.2 of the mc server and i get this when i type java --version:
openjdk 11.0.7 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minecraft 1.10.2 doesn't support Java 11. Downgrade to Java 8.